# In which datatype should i store following string for machine learning models

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have a column in pandas. Which has dtype->object.
For the machine learning model. In which datatype should I convert the column values into ?. So that my machine learning model can recognize it.
One of the STRING value in column

```
'000127127124188187186188184XXX194163164XXX14'
```

I cannot convert it in `int64` because it has

```
'XXX'
```

The string should be converted into the desired datatype

Answer (score 1):

These ID's are just ordinal variables, just like your employee ID in any organisation.
They are not useful in model prediction.
Example:
Lets say you have employee data , which has employee ID and you want to predict salary.
Each employee ID has different salary, so that variable is not showing any trend in your salary, hence will be useless.

Answer (score 0):

An 'object' data type refers to a string, list, dict, etc which is not an int, float, double, etc numerical data type.
Machines can only recognise numerical data (int, float, etc) and not object data types. For a machine learning model these data types have to be 'encoded' or in simple terms converted to a numerical data type because they use mathematical equations, using several available approaches like label encoding, one hot encoding, etc. 
So for your dataset, based on the columns, you have to convert these values to numerical data types using one of the above approaches.

Comment: These str is not categorical variable . So can I use Label Encoding?

Comment: `'000127127124188187186188184XXX194163164XXX14'`, this is a string in itself. If you have alot of rows in your column with the same values, use one hot encoding. If all your rows in this column have different values (are unique), drop the column.

Comment: These whole column is important feature for me.I can't drop the column

Comment: I'm trying to replace 'xxx' with '000' . So that it can become int64 . But Pandas dataframe is not able store that long int value. "Overflow error -> int too big to convert"

Comment: Get the column in a list using `list(df['Column_Name'].values)`. Change the string to an integer using `int(string.replace())`. Python 3.x stores integer values as big as possible till the memory is available.

Comment: I'm not able to store it in pandas dataframe. I have converted above str to int . But now I'm not able to store it in cell of dataframe. ""OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long""

Comment: what form do you have your data in? add an image?

Comment: Data is in dtype->Object .I have to convert it in int64 . so that ml model can recognize.

Comment: No, I mean is it as a csv, list, dictionary, variable?

Comment: Yes . There is one column 'F1' .In cell there is 'str'

Comment: Column in what??? Dataframe? add an image or post an a part of your data.

Comment: Yes column is in dataframe

Comment: But It has unique data. And it's not an categorical feature. There will be N-1 dummy columns generated

Comment: If it has unique data, remove the column.  Why do you need it?

Comment: It is a payment history of each I'd

Comment: Can't help if you don't show your data. How do you think this column helps the model prediction?

Comment: Do you have any suggestion that how should I use these for machine learning model

Comment: ID1   -> 000000000000000000000000000000000000XX000000000000
ID2   -> 000000030000000000000000000000000000000000
ID3   ->000127127124188187186X194163164XXX103072044014

Comment: Each ID has a these Feature

Comment: Then this column definitely doesn't make sense.